# Commands not working with Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

> FatalErrorException in UserStoreCommand.php line 8: Interface
>   'Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling' not found

Here is Code i am using, where its throwing error.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling; 
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel;

class UserStoreCommand implements SelfHandling {
```

I have found same issue was with laravel 5.3 
[here is link](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/908)

Please me know if there is any way to use it with laravel 5.4.

Comment: remove this line use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling; 
 and check and you may check like this too extends Command implements SelfHandling, if doesn't work add namespace of app/Commands

Comment: @rahul_m : Thank you for quick one! It solved. you saved lot of time. ;)
"namespace of app/Commands" It was already there. Just need to remove "Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling" and its solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possibilities to let this happen, solutions can vary

1. remove this line use `Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;`
2. `extends Command implements SelfHandling`
3. `use app/Commands;`

Either of them should work,

And once please go through release notes of [laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/releases#laravel-5.4).

Give it a try, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, SelfHandling is deprecated in laravel 5.4. It's now default so you do not need `use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;` and make sure to remove this `implements SelfHandling`. It should work then.